# MongoBI connector set limit and skip before the lookup command

Tags: mongodb

We are using MongoDB BI Connector (https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master) to index documents into an internal search engine. To do that, we configure a drdl schema with an aggregate pipeline. We have some improvements to do since the query is very slow.

During the translation of the SQL query to the final aggregation pipeline, we saw that the following query is executed.

An example SQL that we execute to index part of the document is

```sql
SELECT *
FROM services
         INNER JOIN ba ON services.`service.idBA` = ba.`_id`
LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 19046000
```

Then, the following aggregation pipeline is built in the mongobi connector (from the logs `-vv`)

```js
    # This is the part that comes from the drdl schema
    {"$addFields": {"service": {"$map": {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$services"},"as": "i","in": "$$i.v"}},"person": "$_id"}},
    {"$unwind": "$service"},

    # This is the part that is generated from the JOIN clause of the SQL query
    {"$match": {"service.idBA": {"$ne": null}}},
    {"$lookup": {"from": "ba","localField": "service.idBA","foreignField": "_id","as": "__joined_ba"}}
    {"$unwind": "$__joined_ba"},
    {"$skip": NumberLong("19046000")},
    {"$limit": NumberLong("100000")},
```

As you can see, the skip and limit operations are made at the end of the pipeline. We suspect that the pipeline is really slow because of that, since there is not need to made the lookup operation before the skip and limit. We would like a pipeline more like that to be executed

```
    # This is the part that comes from the drdl schema
    {"$addFields": {"service": {"$map": {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$services"},"as": "i","in": "$$i.v"}},"person": "$_id"}},
    {"$unwind": "$service"},

    # Move the cursor before the join op
    {"$skip": NumberLong("19046000")},
    {"$limit": NumberLong("100000")},

    # This is the part that is generated from the JOIN clause of the SQL query
    {"$match": {"service.idBA": {"$ne": null}}},
    {"$lookup": {"from": "ba","localField": "service.idBA","foreignField": "_id","as": "__joined_ba"}}
    {"$unwind": "$__joined_ba"},
```

Question is, is there any way to tell to Mongo BI connector to set the limit and skip close before the lookup operation ?

Comment: So have you tried to use `skip` and `limit` before `lookup`?

Comment: The aggregation pipeline is generated by the BI connector, so i cannot do that manually

Comment: Do you have the ability to change SQL query?

Comment: Yes I do, but the issue that i encounter seems to be a bug from the connector BI query optimization than a problem from the SQL Query itself.

Comment: BI connector translates SQL queries between your BI tool and MongoDB. Try to limit and offset before join in your SQl query and check the result.

Comment: Well, the request seems to be incorrect because of that ```error: unexpected LIMIT at position 52 near limit```

Comment: Which request do you use?

Comment: The one that is in the question (sorry, need to remove the extra quotes)

```SELECT * FROM services LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 19046000 INNER JOIN ba ON services.service.idBA = ba_id```

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM services LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 19046000)  s ... `

Comment: Great idea. That seems to be a bit better. The generated pipeline a quite messy, but it does the job. I will relaunch the process to see if the indexation time is better.
Could you add an answer to the question to mark it as resolve ?

Comment: You have a `direction to move` so keep trying ))) I'll add it in 10 minutes. (Printing from the phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, try to limit your `services` collection before joining:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM services LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 19046000) s
  INNER JOIN ba ON s.`service.idBA` = ba.`_id`
```